How can i make my code rerun after Ending?

        switch(choice) {
            case 1: 
                double sum = 0;
                for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter " + i + "th number: ");
                    double number = input.nextDouble();
                    sum = sum + number;
                }
                System.out.println("The sum of 5 numbers is " + sum);
            break;

            case 2:
                double subtract = 0;
                for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter " + i + "th number: ");
                    double number = input.nextDouble();
                    subtract = subtract - number;
                }
                System.out.println("The subtract of 5 numbers is " + subtract);
            break;

            case 3:
                double multiply = 1;
                for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter " + i + "th number: ");
                    double number = input.nextDouble();
                    multiply = multiply * number;
                }
                System.out.println("The multiply of 5 numbers is " + multiply);
            break;

            case 4:
                double divide = 1;
                for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter " + i + "th number: ");
                    double number = input.nextDouble();
                    divide = divide / number;
                }
                System.out.println("The divide of 5 numbers is " + divide);
            break;

            case 5:
               System.exit(0);

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid choice");
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid choice");
        }
    }
}

This is my Code ( A simple Calculator ) Now i want it to rerun after it goes to default amd case 5 Please tell me if i can do anything also How can i make this code shorter
I tries using the Sytem. Stuff but i got to know that there is no command that can do what i desire
So if you can help me please do so! It would mean a lot to me :D
I tried using chatgpt but still got no answer

Which code construct generally allows or causes repetition of execution?

@g00se the question is about repetitively asking the user for an input representing a command until an end sign is given and basically a loop suffices for this goal.

@LajosArpad, the idea is for the OP to answer that question, not you ;)

Sure. I will give you two soutions. The first is a beginner solution, the second is a more advanced solution. The reason for showing them both is to explain why the advanced solution is better.
int choice = -1;
while (choice !== 5) {
    System.out.println("1. sum, 2. sub, 3. mul, 4.div, 5. quit");
    int choice = input.nextInt();
        switch(choice) {
            case 1: 
                double sum = 0;
                for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter " + i + "th number: ");
                    double number = input.nextDouble();
                    sum = sum + number;
                }
                System.out.println("The sum of 5 numbers is " + sum);
            break;

            case 2:
                double subtract = 0;
                for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter " + i + "th number: ");
                    double number = input.nextDouble();
                    subtract = subtract - number;
                }
                System.out.println("The subtract of 5 numbers is " + subtract);
            break;

            case 3:
                double multiply = 1;
                for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter " + i + "th number: ");
                    double number = input.nextDouble();
                    multiply = multiply * number;
                }
                System.out.println("The multiply of 5 numbers is " + multiply);
            break;

            case 4:
                double divide = 1;
                for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter " + i + "th number: ");
                    double number = input.nextDouble();
                    divide = divide / number;
                }
                System.out.println("The divide of 5 numbers is " + divide);
            break;

            case 5:
               System.out.println("Good Bye!");
               break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid choice");
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid choice");
        }
}

This will repeat the commands until a 5 is given. But, here we repeat the loop, mix up representation with computation, etc. A much better approach is to separate concerns, steps:
1. Implement the helper functions
protected double sum(double a, double b) {
    return a + b;
}

protected double sub(double a, double b) {
    return a - b;
}

protected double mul(double a, double b) {
    return a * b;
}

protected double div(double a, double b) {
    return a / b;
}

2. Have a loop and cal the method
protected double loopCall(choice) {
    double value = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter " + i + "th number: ");
        double number = input.nextDouble();
        switch (choice) {
            case 1: {
                value = sum(value, number);
            } break;
            case 2: {
                value = sub(value, number);
            } break;
            case 3: {
                value = mul(value, number);
            } break;
            case 4: {
                value = div(value, number);
            } break;
        }
    }
    return value;
}

3. Do the outer stuff:
int choice = -1;
String op = {"sum", "sub", "mul", "div"};
while (choice !== 5) {
    System.out.println("1. sum, 2. sub, 3. mul, 4.div, 5. quit");
    int choice = input.nextInt();
    if (choice >= 1 && choice <= 4) {
        double value = loopCall(choice);
        System.out.println("The " + op[choice - 1] + " of 5 numbers is " + sum);
    } else if (choice == 5) {
        System.out.println("Good Bye!");
    } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid choice");
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid choice");
    }
}

We do not repeat much of the code, it's easier to understand and maintaint.

Thank you very much Mr.Lajos, I acutally didnt quite understand the after one But i guess for now the Beginner one works better for me  :D.
Thank you again for helping me! Have a great day :)

@PrimeYt happy to help. When you feel like having an adventure, then you can always resort to the advanced solution, because it's better on the long run.

Add a boolean before your code:
boolean running = true;

Put your switch code into a while loop:
while (running) {

And edit your case 5:
case 5:
   running = false;
   break;


Hmm so i just make a variable and make it false and end the code with it?
Thanks Radek :D

@PrimeYt Yes, try it and let me know :)
